# VBA - Excel to PowerPoint - Shape D

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Creating a PowerPoint presentation from an Excel sheet, I can copy graphs and paste without problems.

When it's done to a table it's pasted correctly, but as soon as I click the slide the table moves out of alignment.

I simply need the tables to not move.

**Code Attempt:**

```
'Slide10 -------------------------------------------------------
Set pptsld = pptppt.Slides.Add(10 + 9 * x, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
pptsld.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = Sheets(x + 2).Range("C29")

Sheets(x + 2).Range("Tab_Final").Copy
pptsld.Shapes.Paste
pptsld.Shapes(2).Height = 16 * 28.3646
pptsld.Shapes(2).Width = 33.87 * 28.3646
pptsld.Shapes(2).Left = 0
pptsld.Shapes(2).Top = 3.05 * 28.3646
```

After running the code:
[image: After running the code]

After clicking each Slide:
[image: After clicking each Slide]

Comment: If your presentation includes a table placeholder on a custom layout, the positioning will be automatic and correct.

Comment: Hi John!
Thanks for your help!
But there is no placeholder in this presentation.

Comment: I was suggesting that you make one. Using the built-in capabilities of an application always makes programming it simpler.

Comment: Ahh!
Thanks, I will try that!